# Magento 1 - module controller not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Tyring to create a module where i can create a product dynamically using catalog->products model,  and redirect control to the product's review page. Need only single controller with single action. No blocks, helpers, templates.... nothing required.

But it seems like controller action is not properly routed, there is some mistake in code or configuration ... getting 404 not found error

**Trying this url:**

```
http://localhost/magento_test/dynamicproduct/index/index
```

Namespace: Waqasalieee

Module name: Dynamicproduct

**Magento version:** 1.7.0.2

**Here are the file contents:**

local/Waqasalieee/Dynamicproduct/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
    class Waqasalieee_Dynamicproduct_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
        public function indexAction() {
            die('working in index');
        }
    }
?>
```

local/Waqasalieee/Dynamicproduct/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Waqasalieee_Dynamicproduct>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Waqasalieee_Dynamicproduct>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <dynamicproduct>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Waqasalieee_Dynamicproduct</module>
                    <frontName>dynamicproduct</frontName>
                </args>
            </dynamicproduct>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

app/etc/modules/Waqasalieee_Dynamicproduct.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Waqasalieee_Dynamicproduct>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Waqasalieee_Dynamicproduct>
    </modules>
</config>
```

It should show some error or 'working in index' (string) **but its giving 404 not found error.**

Comment: Please use <codePool> , big P.

Comment: its codePool not codepool....

Comment: :) yes its codePool. @Magento: this is not fair :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your config.xml use codePool instead of codepool.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Waqasalieee_Dynamicproduct>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Waqasalieee_Dynamicproduct>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same sympton and landed here. For me the error was not a erroneous XML config but that the Store Code was actually added to the URL (that's a magento feature, not a bug) and so my controller was only accessible by adding a valid store code to the URL like `http://mystore/<storecode>/<controller>/<action>`.
In my case `http://mage.localhost/en/customer/check`

Comment: Old but (pure) gold! Thanks alot for this hint. After 1h of pulling hairs (knowing my code must be right) your post saved me!